# How do I generate SWX data files serverside?

Tags: database, flash, actionscript, swx

By storing data in [SWX files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWX_Format) on the server, it can be interpreted automatically like loading one SWF into another.

Now I'd like this data to be modified by server side code, how can I do this? Are there any SWX libraries for PHP that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want store images or other assets I would suggest [swfmill](http://swfmill.org/).

The project [swx-format](http://code.google.com/p/swx-format/) seems to have all the things you need.

Maybe also interesting for you: [Haxe](http://haxe.org/) (programming language, generating PHP, swf, neko, js, AS3) has a library [hxformat](http://code.google.com/p/hxformat/) to create swf and abc code on the server side.

Comment: "seems to have all the things you need" -- Where ?? Can you give me a deep link that answers my question?

Comment: Version 2.00 of SWX offers AS3 support using a pure PHP assembler. (http://code.google.com/p/swx-format/wiki/About_SWX_v2)
But documentation seems to be poor.

Comment: Wow! That's great, I'll check it out.